# How to get the MediaRecorder setMaxDuration callback?

Tags: android, callback, mediarecorder

The MediaRecorder allows for the setting of both duration and file size, but I've yet to figure out how to get the callback event for handling. I've gotten recording up and running by closely following the docs here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

I've implemented the `MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener`, which I was guessing would be the one that listened for those two events.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {
    /* code here */
}
```

I added in the duration I want `mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000);`

Finally I have put the required callback method for the OnInfo listener, but it never seems to fire.

```
@Override
public void onInfo(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    Log.i("CALLBACK", "Response Code: " + arg1);
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `setMaxDuration` states that you should _"Call this after setOutFormat() but before prepare()"_. Are you doing that?

Comment: I'm setting it before prepare, but I haven't set setOutputFormat. It doesn't seem to be required for anything before API 8. I am however setting it after setProfile.

Answer (score 0):

Set MediaRecoder listener as `recorder.setOnInfoListener(this);` after implementing the MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener interface

To get the maxDuration and maxFileSize callback use the onInfo callback as follows

```
@Override
public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
     if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {

         Log.e("Maximum Duration Reached","Maximum Duration Reached"); 
      } 
     if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {

         Log.e("Maximum File size Reached","Maximum File size Reached"); 
      }
```

Comment: He asked why it is never seems to fire, please read the question.

Answer (score 0):

**The likely problem is that you are not assigning a OnInfoListener to your MediaRecorder object.**

After initializing your MediaRecorder object call 'setOnInfoListener(X)' and set your listener for variable X.

example:

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {
        /* some other code */

        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
            // Maximum Duration Reached
            if (i == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            /* some other code */

            // Initialize MediaRecorder and assign listener
            MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            // Required max length
            mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(VAL_MAX_RECORD_LENGTH);
            // Set listener for MediaRecorder
            mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
        }
    }
```